# Is this a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: oop, solid-principles

I'm reading The Pragmatic Programmer, 20th Anniversary Edition and I'm thinking about whether or not this code snippet violates the Single Responsibility Principle:

```
class Line {

  private double length;
  private Point start;
  private Point end;

  public Line(Point start, Point end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    calculateLength();
  }

  void setStart(Point p) { 
    this.start = p; 
    calculateLength();
  }

  private void calculateLength() {
    this.length = start.distanceTo(end);
  }
}
```

In detail, the method `setStart()` both sets the start position and calculates the updated length. I think this is a violation.

Comment: This is not an SRP violation as there is no reason for `start` and `length` to vary independently. In other words, the two are highly cohesive. See the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/single-responsibility-principle/info) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I think calls to `calculateLength` should be avoided before they are needed. Since it's a private method it can be called when the need arises, not every time the start/end change. This applies to both the `setStart` and `init` methods. So the answer is, yes, it is a violation, and not the only one. An example with a single call to the length might not need the calculation method at all:

```
class Line {

  private Point start;
  private Point end;

  public Line(Point start, Point end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
  }

  void setStart(Point p) { 
    this.start = p; 
  }

  double getLength() {
    return start.distanceTo(end);
  }
}
```

Would examples with more calls need a pre-calculated value? Unless it's called a million times, maybe not. So the length attribute is also unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you saying that's a violation. IMHO the use of the length variable is highly debatable.